# Почему в конце true? ведь true && false = false

Tags: php

```
$a = true ? 'true' : 'false';

echo $a;

$b = (1 > 2) ? 'true' : 'false';

echo $b;

echo ($a && $b) ? 'true':'false';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя же не true и false, а текст 'true', 'false'. Кавычки убери.

Comment: Спасибо, понял)

Answer (score 3):

Пустая строка и `'0'` при приведении к `bool` дают `false`. А все остальные строки при приведении к `bool` дают `true`.

`'false'` - это `true`.

[PHP: Booleans / Converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Ну, не «это `true`», а «работает как `true`» или там «имеет такой же эффект, как и `true`». Хотя Оруэлловская коннотация хороша.

Comment: а я уж подумал, неужели PHP настолько кривой, что 'true' и 'false' в кавычках даются. Спасибо, успокоили )

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `&&` для строк работает по другому.

```
echo (true && false) ? 'true':'false'; // false
echo ('' && '') ? 'true':'false'; // false
echo ('a' && 'c') ? 'true':'false'; // true
```

Нужно заменить `'true'` на `true` и `'false'` на `false`.